# Disable WhatsApp notifications in status bar and notification menu

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace Duos. I want to stop displaying my WhatsApp message notifications in the status bar and the notification menu.

I found the answer for Galaxy S4 that suggests:

- Go to **Settings**
- Choose the **More** tab
- Choose **Application Manager**
- Choose **WhatsApp**
- Turn off **Show notifications**

But in my device I am not able to find a **More** tab in the settings menu. Is there any other solution for this?

Answer (score 7):

You can disable WhatsApp notifications in status bar and notification menu by doing the followings.

- Open Whatsapp.
- Goto `Settings` => `Notifications`
- Under Notifications, choose

  - Notification Tone: Silent
  - Vibrate: Off
  - Popup Notification: No Popup
  - Light: None

[image]

Comment: Tried with this too.with all 4 options but not working. Even i didn't find any other option. Is it not possible to disable the notifications in status bar and also in the list of notification?

Comment: Same problem here, I keep getting notifications in the status bar!

Comment: pretty sure this doesn't work anymore... Probably needs updating.

Answer (score 7):

You need to go into the actual Android settings, and then Application Manager:

Android Settings > Application Manager > WhatsApp

Then untick "Show Notifications".

You can then choose to enable pop-up alerts for messages or groups. (In my case I only wanted an alert if a single person sent something to me - not inane group chatter!)

Answer (score -3):

I disabled the notifications for whatsapp by going to the application manager for the phone.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! This is a question-and-answer site, not a forum. Please use the *Post answer* button only if you have a solution to the problem. If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.